# Getting only first key in for loop when calling some function inside it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function `CellDisplay`. Calling this function in another function `forLaunch`, this `forLaunch` function is getting called again in a loop `Obj.forEach` which consist of array of object. If I log the key `console.log(key)` in the `forLaunch` function it's showing only first key. I need all the key to display. Here is the code below

### Javascript

```js
const CellDisplay = item => {
  switch (item) {
    case 'item1':
      return 'one';
    case 'item2':
      return 'two';
    case 'item3':
      return 'three';
    case 'item4':
      return 'four';
    case 'item5':
      return 'five';
  }
};
const forLaunch = lData => {
  for (const key in lData) {
    console.log(key);
    return CellDisplay(key);
  }
}

const Obj = [{
  Id: 575,
  items: {
    item1: '2020-12-08T10:00:00.000+0000',
    item2: '2020-11-12T00:00:00.000+0000',
    item3: '2020-12-08T10:00:00.000+0000',
    item4: null,
    item5: '2020-12-08T10:00:00.000+0000'
  },
  active: false
}];
Obj.forEach(data => {
  forLaunch(data.items);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a return statement in your for loop that stop the function execution after the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I cannot remove return I need it for some requirement in project 
 and also need all the items to display.Is there any other way to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

You have a return statement in your for loop, so as soon as you hit the return statement the first time, you're broken out of the `forLaunch` method and subsequently, out of the for loop.

If you were to change `return CellDisplay(key)` to `console.log(CellDisplay(key))` for example, you would get all of the CellDisplay values being printed out.

Comment: Doesn't even need the `console.log(CellDisplay(key))`, since there's a log statement just above it already. This is indeed the issue though.

Comment: You're sort of right. The console.log above it just prints out the key, e.g `item1`, but he said he wants to print `one`. Wasn't sure if that meant just `one` or `one` in addition to `item1`

Comment: I want to print all item1
item2
item3
item4
item5

Comment: @anguler-developer oh, well if that's literally all you wanted, then just delete the return line in `forLaunch`

Comment: I am using this code in Gantt chart in my project. so if I remove there my functionality not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362972/in-dhtmlx-gantt-chart-getting-some-repetition-of-data-in-gantt-config-scales

Answer (score 0):

As others said the `return` in your loop short circuits the loop so it only runs once. Remove that, but also change the loop to a `for...of` loop so you get the values of the array (item1, item2, etc..) instead of the index.

```js
const CellDisplay = item => {
  switch (item) {
    case 'item1':
      return 'one';
    case 'item2':
      return 'two';
    case 'item3':
      return 'three';
    case 'item4':
      return 'four';
    case 'item5':
      return 'five';
  }
};
const forLaunch = lData => {
  let tempArr = [];
  for (const key of lData) {
    tempArr.push(CellDisplay(key));
  }
  return tempArr;
}

const Obj = [{
  Id: 575,
  items: {
    item1: '2020-12-08T10:00:00.000+0000',
    item2: '2020-11-12T00:00:00.000+0000',
    item3: '2020-12-08T10:00:00.000+0000',
    item4: null,
    item5: '2020-12-08T10:00:00.000+0000'
  },
  active: false
}];

Obj.forEach(data => {
  let tempArr = forLaunch(Object.keys(data.items));
  console.log(tempArr)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I cannot remove return and also need all the items to display.Is there any other way to handle it?

Comment: @anguler-developer why can't you remove the return? and if you can't remove it what do you expect the return result to be?

Comment: I am using this code in  Gantt chart in my project. so if I remove there my functionality not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362972/in-dhtmlx-gantt-chart-getting-some-repetition-of-data-in-gantt-config-scales

Comment: @anguler-developer how about pushing the cellDisplay values to a temp array and returning that? If this isn't what you're talking about then you'll have to give way more detail on the structure of your code and exactly what you expect for things to work.

Comment: I edited my answer above so check it out again.